# Android Studio Debugging Clearing App Data but data is not getting deleted when running app again?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

I am running my Android app in debug `Build Variant` now I am observing a strange thing that is, whenever I am clearing my `App data` and then running my app again from `Android Studio` then still I am seeing old data which was stored previously in `Shared Preferences` and in RealmDB, but how come this data which I have cleared earlier is coming back again in shared preferences.

Is this a normal behaviour while debugging in Android Studio ??

This is happening every time I am running my app after clearing the App Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

For more details check the related google [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup).